# imdbpy: do not get full writer list from get_movie['writer']

Tags: python, imdb, imdbpy

Checking for the series Firefly http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0303461/.
Given the code:

```
from imdb import IMDb
parser = IMDb()
parsed = parser.get_movie('0303461')
list_writers = parsed['writer']
```

The list parsed['writer'] appears to ignore any writers with less than two episode to their name. 
Calling:

```
parser.update(parsed,'writer')
```

Results in the error:

> 2015-10-06 12:24:05,877 ERROR [imdbpy] /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/imdb/**init**.py:768: unknown information set "writer"

Is this correct functionality, and the full list can only be obtained through the sql database? Or am I doing something wrong?

Responding to the @davide-alberani's commend comment below:

I agree that the fetch was unnecessary, however with or without it, it does not get the entire record that can be seen from imdb itself. Running parsed.get('writer'), I get the following name list: 
    ["Whedon, Joss", "Minear, Tim", "Edlund, Ben", "Molina, Jose"]

The series writing credits [here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0303461/fullcredits?ref_=tt_ql_1), show the following additional writers:

- Cheryl Cain   ... (1 episode, 2002)
- Jane Espenson ... (1 episode, 2002)
- Drew Z. Greenberg ... (1 episode, 2002)
- Brett Matthews    ... (1 episode, 2003)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to fetch that information, since it's already present in the main data of a movie.

So, in your case, you can access: **parsed.get('writer')** to get a list of writers (verified working with the repository version).

If you want to know which data set are available for a movie, you have to call: **parser.get_movie_infoset()** (similar methods are available for person, company and character objects).

If you want to know which info set was already fetched, see the list **parsed.current_info**

Comment: Responded in initial post